# Lower semicontinuity of Lp integral with 0<p<1 with respect to L2 topology

Tags: functional-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

Denote $I_p[u]:=\int_\Omega |u|^p$ with bounded $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ and $0<p<1$.

My question is: Is $I_p$ lower semicontinuous with respect to (strong) $L^2(\Omega)$-topology? I.e., does it hold that
$$
   u_n\to u \mbox{ in } L^2(\Omega) \qquad\implies\qquad I_p[u] \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} I_p[u_n]
$$
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Fatou's Lemma and a.e. convergence of a subsequence.

Comment: I see.. thanks!